# Are Kristoff and Sven orphans?

Tags: plot-explanation, frozen

In the opening of Frozen, we meet young Kristoff and Sven and it appears that they belong to one of the Ice cutters but after the song “Frozen Heart” they leave them behind.  They are then adopted by the Stone trolls but is there an explanation as to why or where their parents are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It's unknown.** But unofficially, Frozen director Jennifer Lee has confirmed that Kristoff is an orphan in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/alittlejelee/status/422384182388482048); this was elaborated upon in [interviews](http://www.ourkidsmom.com/2014/03/interview-filmmakers-disneys-frozen/):

> One of Heather’s readers asked about Kristoff, and Jennifer Lee was excited to tell his story. Kristoff was an orphan and wild child that just couldn’t be tied down to the orphanage. He loved sneaking out and exploring the woods and following the ice teams and befriended Sven in the process.

And finally, of *course* they're orphans... This is [Disney](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-1308584/Why-does-Disney-hate-parents-Ever-noticed-favourite-films-kill-Mum-Dad-.html), after all. ;)